# Google Web App google.script.run not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following .gs:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
}

function goToMaster() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Master Projects')
  sheet.activate()
}
```

The goToMaster() function activates a sheet called "Master Projects"

When running the function by itself, it works properly. However I created an index.html ui to trigger this function by clicking on a div:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.svg" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/abd2f5db30.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="card card--1" id="master-projects">
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Master Projects</h2>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-diagram-project"></i>
      </div>
<script>
    const masterProjects = document.getElementById('master-projects');
    masterProjects.addEventListener('click', doStuff);

  function doStuff() {
    google.script.run.goToMaster();
  }    

  </script>
</body>  

 </html>
```

When clicking the div, nothing happens! I looked everywhere to find a solution but nothing has worked so far.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: What does it mean to work properly? Is your script a bounded project? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I expect to switch to the active sheet in the spreadsheet. When running the function in the .gs by itself, it is doing that; however, when clicking the div in the html it is NOT doing that (i.e., setting the active sheet)

Comment: That is not possible from a web-app, but it's possible to do that from a dialog or sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Try it like this

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.svg" />
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/abd2f5db30.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="card card--1">
      <div class="container">
        <h2>Master Projects</h2>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-diagram-project"  id="master-projects"></i>
      </div>
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    const masterProjects = document.getElementById('master-projects');
    masterProjects.addEventListener('click', doStuff);
  }
  
  function doStuff() {
    google.script.run.goToMaster();
  }    
  </script>
</body>  

 </html>
```

gs:

```
function goToMaster() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Master Sheet')
  sheet.activate()
}

function launchadialog() {
  const ui =  SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("ah2"),"Title")
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you but it says: "Script function not found: doGet"

Comment: Yeah I did not run with a doGet I tested it with just a dialog.  But it should still work

Comment: It is showing the modal but when clicking the div, it's not switching to the desired sheet

Comment: Is it better to do this in a sidebar?

Comment: I want the sidebar or dialog to be always open when opening the spreadsheet

Comment: Sorry it's working now with the modal or sidebar! Thanks a lot!!!